# Automating the Testing of a GUI in JESS

Tags: automation, gui-testing, jess

I wanted to input a matrix to JESS in order to test a GUI, for example having a GUI for the computer test in the textbook, and input the answers to the questions with a matrix for a statistical test. My matrix will be something like M[100][100] with the first column being the label of the answers given to a question and the rest are the data's for that question.

Thank you very much
Ali

Comment: I suppose you'd have to write a lot more to explain what you want to achieve. Also, make sure to provide some Jess code that is trying to do just that. As it stands, it's just a request for code for an incompletely defined project.

Comment: Suppose I have the following deftemplates:
(deftemplate question
  (slot text)
  (slot type)
  (multislot valid)
  (slot ident))

(deftemplate answer
  (slot ident)
  (slot text))

Which are linked to a GUI which will pop-up asking  the Questions, I do not want to answer the questions by hand for each case, 
I want to form a matrix in Java(maybe) having the ident of the answer and the text for each answer.
I don't know where to start the coding, and how to connect these together.
Thanks for any help 
Ali

Comment: Can I use JavaBean's for this purpose?

Comment: Storing and displaying questions, registering and evaluating answers is hardly something that warrants a rule based system, and neither is a statistical test. Also, I don't see the reason for a 100x100 matrix.

Comment: the matrix contains some possible cases for the answers, and the questions will each trigger some rules and set the next questions to be asked. but for testing the system, I want to input a matrix of some possible and practical cases.